# OWL handling duplicate class names with namespaces

Tags: namespaces, rdf, owl, semantic-web

I am testing out building ontologies with OWL and Protoge. Protoge (and I assume therefore, OWL as well), does not allow duplicate entity names. My concern is that certain terms have different meanings depending on context. For example, "thing" has a domain-specific meaning in law, but is also often used in its common meaning in legal documents.

Of course, I could simply differentiate the two by appending a "technical" to each entity that is being given a technical definition.

However, the better approach I think would be namespaces. The same way as in a normal programming language, I can have "thing" defined in file "a", and in file "b", and identify them as "a.thing" and "b.thing". However, OWL imports do not seem to work this way, and entities in imported ontologies are still identified by their raw name, and not by a namespace qualified name.

Therefore, what is the 'correct' way to do this in OWL? Is there any way to introduce namespace to avoid name clashes? Thanks.

EDIT: "thing" is maybe a bad example, since it is also a default entity. But take any example, say, wrongfulness, which also has a different everyday meaning to technical meaning, and both are used.

Comment: *"duplicate entity names"* - well, OWL entities are uniquely identified by URIs/IRIs - there are no "names" in OWL nor RDF. And that said, IRIs are not really designed for providing a human readable name. For that purpose, properties like `rdfs:label` are best practice.

Comment: So, you could just have IRIs with some auto-generated ID, like `ex:123` and `ex:124` both having the same `rdfs:label` e.g. `"wrongfulness"`. Indeed, you could also introduce some context in the URI resp. namespace, like `http://example.org/contextA/wrongfulness` and `http://example.org/contextB/wrongfulness`, but in the end they are just stupid identifiers that don't have to wrap any human readable form.

Answer (score 0):

`Thing` in OWL is the shorthand for `owl:Thing`, where `owl:` is the namespace reserved for the OWL language. When you create an entity in Protege, you need to define a full IRI, where you can use namespaces exactly as you described.

So, yes, it is a good idea and it is already available in Protege (and in a number of libraries that can be used from various programming languages to manipulate OWL files programmatically).

You can change settings in Protege for the full IRI to be displayed, instead of the shortened version or the label (which is a separate statement providing a human readable string as a label for an entity.